# How prove this $|A||M|=A_{11}A_{nn}-A_{1n}A_{n1}$

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

**Question:**

let the matrix

$A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n},i=1,2,\cdots,n,j=1,2,\cdots,n$,  and the matrix

$M=(a_{ij})_{(n-2)\times (n-2)},$

mean  that

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
\vdots& M&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$
show that

$$\det|A|\cdot \det |M|=A_{11}A_{nn}-A_{1n}A_{n1}$$
where $A_{ij}$ is cofactor with the matrix $A$.

This problem is from linear problem book ,and this problem I can't deal it. because this value
$$|A||M|$$ I can't choose something to  deal it?

Comment: math110: I just want to ping you that I made a correction to my answer. I hope that this time it does not contains mistakes. And I hope that someone will be able to come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: You wrote: *This problem is from linear problem book*. Could you tell us the name of the book? (BTW my opinion is that in general it is good to mention source of the problem in the post.)

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** Originally I thought that proof along these lines is quite simple. Later I found a mistake in my attempted proof. (You can see it below.) I still think that the proof can be done this way, but it is rather messy and we have to be careful about the signs and whether no non-zero terms are missing in the sums we obtain. So it is easy to make a mistake. So I hope that somebody will come up with a more elegant approach.

---

First notice that if we multiply the matrix of the above form from the right or from the left by 
$$B'=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&B&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
the both sides of the equality are multiplied by $|B|^2$.

To see this, it suffices to notice that $A$ is multiplied by $B'$ and $|B'|=|B|$. The middle $M$ is changed to $BM$ (or $MB$) so the determinant of the new middle is $|M|\cdot|B|$. And the minors of $A$ which appear on the RHS are multiplied either by $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}$ or by $\begin{pmatrix}B&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. So each determinant is multiplied by $|B|$.

Now we can find non-singular matrices $B_{1,2}$ such that 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&B_1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
\vdots& M&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&B_2&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1n}\\
\vdots& D&\vdots\\
b_{n1}&\cdots&b_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

If $M$ is non-singular, we can simply take $B_1=M^{-1}$ and $B_2=I$, but in any case we can get diagonal matrix from $M$ combining elementary row and elementary column operations.

The above arguments show that it is sufficient to prove this in the case when $M$ is a diagonal matrix.

---

Now if $M=\operatorname{diag}(d_2,\dots,d_{n-1})$ then we can apply [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) to the matrix
$$|A|=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
\vdots& M&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}.$$

By analyzing which permutations have nonzero contribution we find out that
$$|A|=a_{11}d_2\cdots d_{n-1}a_{nn} - a_{1,n}d_2\cdots d_{n-1}a_{n1}
- \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} a_{n,n} a_{i,1}a_{1,i} \frac{d_2\cdots d_{n-1}}{d_i}
- \sum_{j=2}^{n-1} a_{11} a_{j,n}a_{n,j} \frac{d_2\cdots d_{n-1}}{d_i}
+ \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} a_{1,n} a_{i,1}a_{n,i} \frac{d_2\cdots d_{n-1}}{d_i}
+ \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} a_{n,1} a_{i,1}a_{n,i} \frac{d_2\cdots d_{n-1}}{d_i}
+ \sum_{\substack{2\le i,j \le n-1\\i\ne j}}  a_{1,i}a_{n,j}a_{i,1}a_{j,n} \frac{d_2\cdots d_{n-1}}{d_i d_j}
- \sum_{\substack{2\le i,j \le n-1\\i\ne j}}  a_{1,i}a_{n,j}a_{i,n}a_{j,1} \frac{d_2\cdots d_{n-1}}{d_i d_j}
$$
I will not include the detailed analysis of all cases. Let us have a look, for example, what happens if we choose $a_{1,i}$ in the first row and $a_{n,j}$ in the last row. (This requires $i\ne j$.) Then $d_i$ and $d_j$ cannot be used. If we want to get non-zero elements in the remaining $(n-2)$ rows, we must use all remaining diagonal elements. This leaves us with using either $a_{i,1}$ or $a_{i,n}$ in the $i$-th row. This choice determines the choice in the $j$-th row. So we get either $a_{1,i}a_{n,j}a_{i,1}a_{j,n}$ or $a_{1,i}a_{n,j}a_{i,n}a_{j,1}$ multiplied by all diagonal elements with the exception of $d_i$ and $d_j$. Then we also have to check the sign of the permutation.

Using similar analysis we can find out that:

$$A_{11} = a_{11} d_2\cdots d_{n-1} - \sum_{i=2}^n a_{1,i} a_{i,1} d_2\cdots d_{i-1} d_{i+1} \dots d_n $$

$$A_{nn} = a_{nn} d_2\cdots d_{n-1} - \sum_{j=2}^n a_{n,j} a_{j,n} d_2\cdots d_{j-1} d_{j+1} \dots d_n $$

$$A_{n1} = -a_{1n} d_2 \cdots d_{n-1} + \sum_{i=1}^n a_{1,i} a_{i,n} d_2\cdots d_{i-1} d_{i+1} \dots d_n$$

$$A_{1n} = -a_{n1} d_2 \cdots d_{n-1} + \sum_{j=1}^n a_{n.j}a_{j,1} d_2\cdots d_{j-1} d_{j+1} \dots d_n $$

Now we can check that if we multiply $A_{11}A_{nn}-A_{n1}A_{1n}$ we get $|A|\cdot|M|$. (The only minor difference is that we do get also summands for $i=j$, but they cancel out.)

---

**EDIT:** This was my original attempt, which is **incorrect**. Mistakes in this approach are incorrect assumption that only two terms in expansion of $|A|$ are non-zero and incorrect expression of $A_{11}$, $A_{nn}$, $A_{1n}$ and $A_{n1}$.

Now if $M=\operatorname{diag}(d_2,\dots,d_{n-1})$ then we can see directly from [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) that
$$|A|=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
\vdots& M&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix} = a_{11}d_2\dots d_{n-1} a_{nn} - a_{1n} d_2\dots d_{n-1} a_{n1},$$
since the contribution of all other permutations to the determinant is either zero or they come in pairs which cancel out.

And from this we get $$|A|\cdot |M| = 
(a_{11}d_2\dots d_{n-1}) (d_2\dots d_{n-1}a_{nn}) - (a_{1n} d_2\dots d_{n-1}) (d_2\dots d_{n-1}a_{n1}) =
A_{nn}A_{11} - A_{n1}A_{1n}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can play the good old indeterminate trick. Suppose the matrix entries are taken from a field $K$ (an integral domain is also OK: it suffices to prove the equality over its field of fractions). Let $a_{11},\ldots,a_{nn}$ be $n^2$ indeterminates and $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$. Then $A$ is a matrix over the field of fractions $F$ of the polynomial ring $K[a_{11},\ldots,a_{nn}]$. Write
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&p^\top&a_{1n}\\
u     &M     &v\\
a_{n1}&q^\top&a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since the entries of $M$ are $(n-2)^2$ different indeterminates, $M$ is invertible over $F$. Therefore, by performing some appropriate row operations and also some column operations, we get
\begin{align}
|A|
=\left|\begin{matrix}
a_{11}&p^\top&a_{1n}\\
u     &M     &v\\
a_{n1}&q^\top&a_{nn}
\end{matrix}\right|
&=\left|\begin{matrix}
a_{11}-p^\top M^{-1}u&0&a_{1n}-p^\top M^{-1}v\\
u     &M     &v\\
a_{n1}-q^\top M^{-1}u&0&a_{nn}-q^\top M^{-1}v
\end{matrix}\right|\\
&=\left|\begin{matrix}
a_{11}-p^\top M^{-1}u&0&a_{1n}-p^\top M^{-1}v\\
0     &M     &0\\
a_{n1}-q^\top M^{-1}u&0&a_{nn}-q^\top M^{-1}v
\end{matrix}\right| = |B|,
\end{align}
where we denote the big matrix on last line by $B$. Note that the cofactors at the four corners of $A$ are identical to their counterparts of $B$, because we can obtain the corresponding submatrices of $B$ by applying the above row and column operations to the submatrices of $A$. (Alternatively, consider Schur complements.) It is straightforward to verify that
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}
b_{11}&0&b_{1n}\\
0     &M     &0\\
b_{n1}&0&b_{nn}
\end{matrix}\right| |M| = (b_{11}b_{nn}-b_{1n}b_{n1})|M|^2 = B_{11}B_{nn}-B_{1n}B_{n1}.
$$
Therefore the polynomial identity $|A| = A_{11}A_{nn}-A_{1n}A_{n1}$ (here both sides are polynomials in $n^2$ variables $a_{11},\ldots,a_{nn}$) holds as well. So, when the $n^2$ indeterminates are specialised to any $n^2$ values in $K$, the equality also holds.