# Strange phenomena in determinants of matrix of determinants.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

In my research, my computations are giving rise to the following strange phenomena:

Let
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}x_1^p & x_2^p  & x_{3}^p\\
x_{1}^q & x_{2}^q & x_{3}^q\\
x_{1}^r & x_{2}^r & x_{3}^r
\end{bmatrix}$$
and let $\neg x_i^j$ denote the minor of D that is obtained by deleting the row containing $x_i^j$. What I have found is that $$\neg x_1^p \cdot \neg x_2^q -\neg x_1 ^q \cdot \neg x_2 ^p=x_3^r\cdot\det D$$ and similarly for other choices of ordering $p,q,r$ and choices of $1,2,3$.  That is, choosing $i,j\in\{i,j,k\}$ instead of $1,2$ and $a,b\in\{a,b,c\}$ instead of $p,q$ in the above expression, will replace the right hand side with $\pm x_k^r\det D$.

Does anyone know of a general mechanism behind this phenomena? I have carried out the computations explicitly, but they were totally unsuggestive of an intrinsic mechanism.

Comment: Probably related: [q816392](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816392/determinant-identity-det-m-det-n-det-m-ii-det-m-jj-det-m-ij-det) and [q851030](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851030/how-prove-this-am-a-11a-nn-a-1na-n1).